# How do I publish a ClickOnce application using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine

Tags: .net, clickonce, publish, msbuild-buildengine

I have a WPF, ClickOnce application that I am trying to build using the Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.

I believe my question actually boils down to "how do I do the command line /target:publish using Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine"?

I've tried the following

```
projectToBuild.SetProperty("PublishUrl", myPublishUrl);
projectToBuild.Targets.AddNewTarget("publish");
```

but I'm really just guessing at those properties based on the command line properties I'm setting to publish the ClickOnce application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Targets.AddNewTarget appears to be the mechanism for creating a new target.

It appears that the mechanism to build to a target is to use the string parameter on the .Build():

```
projectToBuild.Build("publish");
```